# Non-linear second order ODE with exponential coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE of the form:

$$
\frac{
4M \left[ \left(\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}f(r)\right)^2 r 
- 4\ \left(\frac {{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d} r^2}f(r) \right) r 
- 6\ \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}r}f(r)\right] {\rm e}^{ f \left( r \right)/2 } 
+ r \left[r^2\left({\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}f(r) \right)^3 
- 6\
 \left( \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}f(r)\right)^2 r 
+ 8\ \left(\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}r^2}f(r)\right)r 
+ 16\ \frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}f(r)\right]
}{r^2\left(\left(\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}f(r) 
\right)r - 2 \right)^3} = \frac{\left(-8\ r^2-24A\right) 
\pi}{(r^2+A) ^{2}}$$

Where $M$ and $A$ are constants.
I would be grateful if anyone could help me to solve it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this has an analytic solution?

Comment: @Dylan: Actually No. in fact, this is the last part of a set of calculi which several times  was controlled

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical scheme then? If so, please state that in the question, along with your attempts to solve it / your thoughts on the equation or what the solution may look like.

Comment: @Dylan: first of all thank you. Not sure this equation has an analytical answer but I need an f(r) to describe sth. I 've tried to solve this by Maple and Mathematica which was unsuccessful. Don't know where the problem is.